# C Shell script condition for if string contains a newline character

Tags: string, csh

I'm not sure how to express this using the `csh` string matching syntax. I want to test whether a csh variable contains a newline. I'm basically looking for:

```
if ($mystr !~ <pattern for strings which contain a newline character>)
```

*Edit:* in my particular case, I am trying to make a string like this pass:

```
1234ABC
```

And a string like this fail:

```
1234ABC
 -------
FOOBAR
```

These are the output of a `sed` command, namely `sed '1d;$d'`. Not sure if that matters.

The reason why I am trying to detect newlines rather than `" -------"` is for defense against changes in the formatting of the file I'm parsing. (Anyway, I don't think it matters what I'm doing with the file exactly, since I'm just looking for a general solution for detecting a newline character.)

Comment: Does it _need_ to be `csh`? Do you want to check if the string is contained in `$mystr` or if the two are identical?

Comment: @terdon Yes it does *need* to be `csh`, and I just want to check to see if there is a newline character in `$mystr`.

Comment: What? Do you want to check whether `$mystr` is/contains a specific multiline string or do you just need to check whether `$mystr` contains newline character(s)? The two are completely different. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon There, does that help?

Comment: I edited with what I think you mean. I beleive all you're looking for is the newline character, `\n` but have no `csh` knowledge so I don't know what the match syntax would be or even if `csh` _can_ match.

Comment: Was it really necessary to reiterate the title?

Comment: Well, it was for me, yes. That's why I wasn't understanding. The syntax you show implies that you are matching `$mystr` against a _specific_ multiline variable. I edited to clarify that's not what you're after. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($mystr:q =~ *'\
'*) echo yes
```

should work in some implementations and versions of `csh` (like the `csh` and `tcsh` ones found on Debian). In some others (like the one found on Solaris 10), you may have better luck with

```
set nl = '\
'
if ($mystr:q =~ *$nl:q*) echo yes
```

Most people have given up trying to write reliable scripts with `csh` by now. Why would you use `csh` in this century?

This code works for me (outputs `no`) in `tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,color,filec`

```
set mystr = '1234ABC\
 -------\
FOOBAR'
if ($mystr:q !~ *'\
'*) then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
endif
```

Note that if you do:

```
set var = `some command`
```

`csh` stores each word (blank separated) of the output of `some command` in several elements of the `var` array.

With:

```
set var = "`some command`"
```

it stores each non-empty line in elements of the array.

It looks like one cannot<sup>1</sup> store the output of a command whole into a variable in `(t)csh`, so your only  option would be:

```
set var = "`some command`" # note that it removes the empty lines
if ($#var == 1)...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, that's not true, one could do something like:

```
set x = "`some command | paste -d. /dev/null -`"
set var = ""
set nl = '\
'

foreach i ($x:q)
  set i = $i:s/.//:q
  set var = $var:q$i:q$nl:q
end
```

<sup>(of course, it may not work in all `csh` implementations/versions)</sup>

Comment: When I `ps x` I get `-csh`. Does that mean I'm not running `tcsh`, or does that not tell me anything?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `$var:q` was already available in `csh`. I would still advise against using `(t)csh` for scripting though.

Comment: No idea why you took the disclaimer out of your answer, it was actually pretty good advice.

Comment: I'm getting `if: Badly formed number`. I'm using it like so: `if ($mystr:q !~ *'\
'*) then`. Mind you can't see the newline...

Comment: @2rs2ts, try with the updated answer.

Comment: Still no luck. This is what the version seems to be: `tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,color,filec` (CentOS 6 here.) The reason why I'm doing it in `csh` is because I'm editing legacy `csh` code.

Comment: @2rs2ts Both work for me with that same version of `tcsh`. Does that work if you put that code by itself in a file and run it?

Comment: Hmm, yes it does. In truth `$mystr` is the result of a `sed '1d;$d'` call in my script (i.e. `set mystr=\`cat somefile.txt | sed '1d;$d'\``.) I don't know, could that be related to the problem? I was able to successfully check if `$mystr != ""`.

Comment: @2rs2ts, I can't tell as I can't reproduce. Possibly the variable contains a value that triggers a bug. It looks somehow, tcsh is trying to interpret something as a number and fails to parse it. (like `if (09 > 1)` would cause that same error message).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The string in question starts with a numeral, but it contains whitespace, letters, and special characters. So can I do anything about this?

Comment: @2rs2ts, can you post a sample string that exhibits the problem? Otherwise you could try `if (x$mystr:q !~...` to see if that helps.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I got `if: Expression Syntax.` I will edit my question with an example string.

Comment: OK, I get it, your variable is an array.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks, but I don't understand the purpose of `set var = "\`some command\`"` followed by `set myvar = "\`some command\`"`. Seems to me that they're exactly the same...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14401/discussion-between-2rs2ts-and-stephane-chazelas)

Comment: Electrical Engineers predominantly use csh/tcsh because of the EDA and CAD software still using csh scripts. The comments about 'don't use csh' get old, and come from people unaware of valid reasons and unimaginative enough to think of any