# tcsh preserve newlines in command substitution `...`

Tags: tcsh, command-substitution

So, I wrote a simple script to convert `sh`-style `export key=value` statements to `csh-style` `setenv key value` for `docker-machine env`.

```
#!/bin/sh
docker-machine env | sed -e 's/export/setenv/' -e 's/=/ /' -e '$d'
echo '# eval `docker-machine env`'
```

and it produces the following output

```
setenv DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY "1"
setenv DOCKER_HOST "tcp://<ipv4 address>:<port>"
setenv DOCKER_CERT_PATH "<HOME>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
setenv DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME "default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval `docker-machine env`
```

In my `.tcshrc` I've bound this script to the alias `docker-machine-env-csh`.

I can source the output of this script using a temporary variable just fine

```
% docker-machine-env-csh >! /tmp/csh && source /tmp/csh
```

However, I don't seem to be able to directly `eval` the result of this alias

```
% eval `docker-machine-env-csh`
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

Or assign it to a variable in a way that preserves newlines.

```
% set a = `docker-machine-env-csh`
% printf "%s\n" "$a"
setenv ... setenv ... setenv ...
```

Although, weirdly `` printf "%s\n" `docker-machine-env-csh` `` seems to insert a newline between every token.

```
% printf "%s\n" `docker-machine-env-csh`
setenv
...
...
setenv
...
...
```

How do I preserve newlines in `tcsh` command substitution?

Comment: See: [C Shell script condition for if string contains a newline character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128364)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of good reasons why it's recommended not to use `csh` or `tcsh` for scripting. That's one of those.

To get the output of `some command` verbatim into a shell variable in `tcsh`, you need something like:

```
set temp = "`(some command; echo .) | paste -d . - /dev/null`"
set var = ""
set nl = '\
'
foreach i ($temp:q)
  set var = $var:q$i:r:q$nl:q
end
set var = $var:r:q
```

Don't forget to use `$var:q` syntax to expand the variable as in:

```
printf '<%s>\n' $var:q
```

The POSIX `sh` equivalent would be:

```
var=$(some command; echo .)
var=${var%.}
```

Now, if your `docker-machine-env-csh` command did output the information on one line only, or at least with each line terminated with a `;` and without comments so that when joined with  spaces they still are valid csh code (like applications such as `dircolors` or `ssh-agent` do when they  want their output to be passed to `csh`'s `eval`), then you could do:

```
set var = "`docker-machine-env-csh`"
printf '%s\n' "$var"
# or printf '%s\n' $var:q
# or printf '%s\n' "$var:q"
```

With `` set var = `docker-machine-env-csh` ``, `tcsh` splits on blanks (and creates an array variable), while with `` set var = "`docker-machine-env-csh`" ``, it splits on newline only (still an array variable, but if the output has only one line, that array has only one element).

Here you can use `"$var"` in place of `$var:q` because `$var` doesn't contain newline characters. `"$var"` would join the array elements with space while `$var:q` would preserve them (here there's only one element, so it makes no difference). If those array elements may contain newlines and you wanted to join them with space, you'd use `"$var:q"`.

So maybe you can modify your script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
docker-machine env | sed '
  s/export/setenv/
  s/=/ /
  /^#/!s/$/;/
  $d'
echo '# eval "`docker-machine env`"'
```