# Why can't echo and printf output variables that have only whitespace characters?

Tags: terminal, variable, command, android, dash

```
var1=$(printf "\n\x0A\n")

var2=$(printf "\na\nb\nc")
```

Using Android Terminal, the output of `echo -e "$var1"` (same for echo and printf) iss nothing, not even the 3 new lines. But `echo -e "$var2"` or `echo "$var2"` or `printf "$var2"` output:

```
a
b
c
```

How come $var2's output includes the whitespace character but not $var1?

(`\n` and `\x0A` have the exact same behaviour.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does shell Command Substitution gobble up a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline-char) (note that it's not just one trailing newline - all trailing newline characters are removed)

Comment: Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383217/shell-keep-trailing-newlines-n-in-command-substitution

Comment: Replace teh double quots with single quotes, and put everything after the `=` sign between double quotes

Comment: Note also that `echo` inserts a newline after the output, but `printf` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you print a result of a printf?

```
var1="\n\x0A\n"
var2="\na\nb\nc"

printf $var1
printf $var2
```

that should work.

*nix system - LF, 0x0A (dec 10) `\n` as line ending

windows OS - CR LF, 0x0D 0x0A (dec: 13 10) `\r \n` as line ending.