# Bash and other shells $(...) remove the ending newline character

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh, printf

Why the **shell** structure **`$(...)` removes the ending newline character**?

```
#!/bin/bash

S='a
b
'
printf '%i [%s]\n' "${#S}" "$S"

T=$(printf '%s' "$S")
printf '%i [%s]\n' "${#T}" "$T"
```

That prints this:

```
4 [a
b
]
3 [a
b]
```

The variable `S` contains 2 newline characters.
The first `printf` prints it correctly.
Then the second `printf` prints `S` and assigns the exact same result to `T` via the `$(...)` evaluation. Finally the third `printf` shows that **the last newline character is missing in `T`! Why?**

I have the same result with sh, ksh and Zsh.

Comment: Related: [shell: keep trailing newlines ('\n') in command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383217) or [How to preserve the newline character (\n) when capture output of a command in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248226) or [Bash option to make command substitution preserve trailing newlines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606735)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented behaviour; `man bash`:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

Of course, you could argue that this does not answer a "Why?" question.

I am not aware of an official explanation. My guess is that it makes sense because it is what you usually need. Adding newline is also easier than removing newline.

```
# This is how people are used to print text
echo foo

# In the other scenario this would end in two newlines at the end
echo foo "$(whatever)"

# could behandled with echo -n or printf but who would consider that an improvement?
```

Another reason is that some commands add a newline at the end and others don't. This behaviour relieves the user of the burden to care about this difference.

## avoiding this effect

You can do this in order to get the real command output:

```
T=$(whatever; echo x)
T_real="${T%x}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the exact result? Of course I can add a newline myself. But I want a newline only when there is really a newline in the content.
(I have a workaround. Always add a final character and then remove it. But it is dirty.)

Comment: @OlivierPirson See my edit

Comment: Nice. I had more or less the same idea but yours is better. And compatible with sh.

Comment: `x` is not the best choice of a character to append there. See the linked Q&As for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That is an interesting problem but none of your answers gives a hint how that could become a problem in practice. You add an `x`, you remove an `x`. Nothing can go wrong there. Unless you change the encoding between these consecutive operations which would be closer to sabotage than to programming.

Comment: It's to piss of Perl programmers who were hoping to demonstrate their chops.

Comment: [shell: keep trailing newlines ('\n') in command substitution](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/383411) gives a practical example. Adding a `x` can complete an unfinished / truncated character like the `ū` in a locale using the BIG5HKSCS charset (as used in the zh_HK locale on Ubuntu 22.04 at least for instance) as mentioned there. And it's that `ū` character, not the last byte of it that `${T%x}` would remove. Adding a `.` or `/` instead doesn't have the problem as their encoding is guaranteed not to be found in other characters.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Unusefully, [because the standard says so](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

> ...replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution.

Realistically, probably because it always worked like that (considering that POSIX mostly codifies existing behaviour, as far as I understand).

More usefully, it might be so that you can do e.g. this:

```
echo "$(date +"%F %T") $(hostname): something happened..."
```

instead of

```
t=$(date +"%F %T")
t=${t%
}
h=$(hostname)
h=${h%
}
echo "$t $h: something happened..."
```

That is, most commands that print some single value likely print the newline at the end so that they're more friendly to use on the command line. (Without the shell having to detect the cursor not being at the beginning of line after a command; zsh does that, most others don't.)
But if you're going to use that value in a script for something else, you probably don't want the newline, just the content. This doesn't only go for printing, but also for passing the value as an argument to some command.

The common workaround *is* to append an extra character and to remove it:

```
foo=$(printf 'foo\n'; echo .)
foo=${foo%.}
echo "<$foo>"
```

Or, if you only have a `printf` inside the command substitution, use `printf -v` where available:

```
printf -v foo 'foo\n'
```

Comment: `printf -v` is really nice for Bash, but not compatible with sh and ksh.

Comment: Removing one trailing newline character is usually desirable, but removing all of them like most shells do is IMO a bug.

Comment: @OlivierPirson, `printf -v` is also available in the builtin `printf` of recent versions of zsh and ksh93.